# Explain find command with options

Tags: command-line, find

I am fairly new to more complex linux commands and this one has a bunch of options and flags that I have never seen and piecing these together just won't click in my brain.

`find /external-disk/postgresql_wals_backup -type f -mtime -2 -exec cp {} /work-disk/postgresql-scripts/wal_backup_script_dir/ \;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `find` : command
- `/external-disk/postgresql_wals_backup` : the path we are searching in
- `-type f`: only look for files (No directories, links, etc)
- `-mtime -2`: only look for files that have been modified 48 hours ago (-2: 2*24)
- `-exec cp {} /work-disk/postgresql-scripts/wal_backup_script_dir/ \;`:

  - execute `cp` command on each file you have found
  - `{}` is just a placeholder for files that we found
  - Which copies all files that have been found to `/work-disk/postgresql-scripts/wal_backup_script_dir/`.

Comment: How did you write it that fast?

Comment: @Pilot6 Was it really fast?  :))

Comment: Wow quick response, thanks so much for the clear answer.